# hackerank shows this message: ~ no response on stdout ~ and ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2 3 6 6 5'

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, error-handling

```
def num(n):

    list1=[]


    for i in range(n):
        a=int(input())
        list1.append(a)
    print(list1)
    a=max(list1)

    while max(list1)==a:
        list.remove(a)
        print(list1)

    return max(list1)
       


if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())
    num(n)
```

#while running the question in hackerrank

## it shows this message ------- ~ no response on stdout ~

Comment: Please don't use ```list``` built in as a variable. Also, there is nothing to receive the returned value

Answer (score 0):

You are returning the value from the function, but you are not assigning it to a variable, nor printing it. Also, kindly refrain from using built-in functions like `list` as variables as they can later cause problems

```
def num(n):

    list1=[]


    for i in range(n):
        a=int(input())
        list1.append(a)
    print(list1)
    a=max(list1)

    while max(list1)==a:
        list1.remove(a)
        print(list1)

    return max(list1)
       


if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())
    print(num(n))
```

Comment: i forgot to mention  that it also shows--ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2 3 6 6 5'